LLAMA Vector Indexing with Hugging face: The `model_name` argument must be provided
It looks like llama is defaulting to OpenAI.
I am using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8n2Se8PAXg&list=PLBSCvBlTOLa-vUt7mCECzaJjJEjos6K-l&index=7
And saw this interesting article: Why does llama-index still require an OpenAI key when using Hugging Face local embedding model?
Still I am not able to solve my problem.
To me, my model name is already defined in "llm". I think I need to use the service context, but without success. It still asks to provide the model name.
import os
from getpass import getpass
from huggingface_hub import login
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader
from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex
from llama_index.llms.huggingface import HuggingFaceInferenceAPI

reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files= ["acquisition2.csv"])
documents = reader.load_data()

HF_TOKEN = os.environ["HF_TOKEN"] = "XXXXXXX"
login(token=HF_TOKEN)

# create llm model

llm = HuggingFaceInferenceAPI(model_name="mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1", token=HF_TOKEN)

index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents,embed_model="local")

ValueError: The model_name argument must be provided.
Adding the model_name as a parameter is still throwing an error.

Faced the same issue while following this video tutorial, I guess we have to pass the model_name therefore found this is in documentation.
from llama_index.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbedding
from llama_index.core import Settings

embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbedding(
    model_name="BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5"
    )
vector_index=VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(document,embed_model=embed_model)


You define the llm but you don't supply it to the vector store anywhere.
How about:
import os
from getpass import getpass
from huggingface_hub import login
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader
from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex
from llama_index.llms.huggingface import HuggingFaceInferenceAPI
from llama_index import ServiceContext

reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files= ["acquisition2.csv"])
documents = reader.load_data()

HF_TOKEN = os.environ["HF_TOKEN"] = "XXXXXXX"
login(token=HF_TOKEN)

# create llm model

llm = HuggingFaceInferenceAPI(
    model_name="mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1", 
    token=HF_TOKEN
)

service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
    llm=llm, 
    embed_model="local",
)

index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
    documents, 
    service_context=service_context,
)

